# Do DOM events work with pointer lock?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, fullscreen, pointerlock

I have used the pointer lock on my canvas element, and the canvas is on full screen. I want to detect right clicks and left clicks to respond to them. Is it possible to respond to clicks in full screen and pointer lock? I already know how to use the pointer lock api and the fullscreen api, I don't want any answers explaining how to use them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the experiments I've done, the short answer is "it depends." Take a look at the following demo. There is a canvas scaled to be a quarter of the screen size in each dimension. When you move the cursor over it, a white circle appears on the canvas. When you left click, you'll draw a red circle to the canvas, and when you right click, you'll draw a cyan circle to the canvas. When you click the "Full screen" button, you'll activate pointer lock and enter fullscreen mode. If you press the "Esc" key, you'll exit pointer lock and fullscreen mode.

**Note that you'll need to copy and paste the code into a file and load it. The demo won't run if you just click "Run code snippet."**

As far as your question, there are two issues, I'm aware of:

1. In Chrome, both right- and left-click events are triggered even while in fullscreen/pointer lock. However, *in Firefox, only left-click events are triggered*; I was unable to get right-click events using any of the handlers I tried (`click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `contextmenu`). When not in fullscreen/pointer lock, both left- and right-click events get triggered as expected in both browsers. If anyone has any solutions for listening to right-click events while in fullscreen/pointer lock, I'd love to hear them.
2. It seems that *in pointer lock in both Chrome/Firefox, events no longer trickle down to elements contained in the element with pointer lock, but they continue to bubble up to parent elements.* So in the demo, the `canvas` is inside a `div`. The `div` has pointer lock. `onclick` handlers are attached to the `canvas`, `div`, and `document` to report click events in the console. Without pointer lock, clicking on the canvas triggers `onclick` handlers for all three elements (`canvas`, `div`, and `document`). However, with pointer lock on the `div`, the `onclick` handler for the `canvas` never gets triggered, though the handlers for the `div` and the `document` do.

I also identified a couple other quirks to Firefox that, while not directly related to your initial question, might be helpful to folks interested in implementing this sort of thing:

1. When fullscreen mode is entered, Firefox will apply styles to the fullscreen element to get it to fill the screen. I was unable to get the `canvas` styled correctly (i.e. to take up the full screen) when it was placed full screen. Rather, I had to wrap the `canvas` in a `div` and enter full screen on the `div`. See the [Fullscreen API documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Presentation_differences) for more info:

> if you're trying to emulate WebKit's behavior on Gecko, you need to place the element you want to present inside another element, which you'll make fullscreen instead, and use CSS rules to adjust the inner element to match the appearance you want.

2. In Firefox, activating fullscreen mode deactivated pointer lock. In order to get both activated, I had to first activate fullscreen mode and then activate pointer lock. However the simple two lines of code:

   ```
   canvasContainer.requestFullscreen();
   canvasContainer.requestPointerLock();
   ```

   *did not work*. My understanding of what was happening is that the call to requestPointerLock got initiated before full screen mode was fully established. This led to pointer lock being activated and then quickly deactivated again. I found it necessary to wait until fullscreen mode was fully established before calling `requestPointerLock()`. Checking that `document.mozFullScreenElement !== null` seemed to be sufficient for checking that full screen mode was completely operational. The following following click handler definition worked to solve this problem for me:

   ```
   document.getElementById('fullscreen_button').onclick = function(e) {
          // When button is clicked, enter both full screen and pointer lock
       canvasContainer.requestFullscreen();
       var timeout = 2000;
       var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
           if (document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) {
               window.clearInterval(interval);
               canvasContainer.requestPointerLock();
           } else if (timeout <= 0) {
               addErrorMessage('Unable to establish pointer lock.');
               clearTimeout(interval);
           } else {
               timeout -= 50;
           }
       }, 50);
   }
   ```

   This function repeatedly checks if full screen mode is established. When it is, it initiate pointer lock. If fullscreen mode can't be determined after 2 s, it times out.

I haven't done any testing in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="msgs">Click 'Full screen' button below to go full screen. <br>
  Click the left mouse button to draw a red circle. <br>
  Click any other mouse button to draw a cyan circle. <br>
  Press the 'Esc' key to exit full screen.</p>
  <div id="canvas_container">
    <canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id='fullscreen_button'>Full screen</button>
</body>
  <script>

    // Display constants
    var CANVAS_BG_COLOR = 'rgb(75, 75, 75)';
    var LEFT_CLICK_COLOR = 'rgb(255, 150, 150)';
    var OTHER_CLICK_COLOR = 'rgb(150, 255, 255)';
    var CURSOR_COLOR = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
    var CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR = 4;              // Ratio between screen dimension and canvas dimension before going full-screen

    // Store mouse position
    var mouseX, mouseY;

    // Setup onscreen canvas, smaller than the screen by a factor of CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = screen.width/CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;
    canvas.height = screen.height/CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;

    // Create an offscreen canvas that's the same as the size of the screen
    var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var offscreenCtx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
    offscreenCanvas.width = screen.width;
    offscreenCanvas.height = screen.height;
    
    var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas_container');

    // Radius of the circle drawn and of the circle cursor
    var circleRadius = 12;
    var cursorRadius = circleRadius/CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR

    offscreenCtx.drawCircle = ctx.drawCircle = function (x, y, color, radius) {
        this.fillStyle = color;
        this.beginPath();
        this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
        this.fill();
    }

    offscreenCtx.clearCanvas = function() {
        this.fillStyle = CANVAS_BG_COLOR;
        this.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    ctx.update = function() {
        // Copy the offscreen canvas, scaling down if not in full-screen mode
        this.drawImage(offscreenCanvas, 0, 0, offscreenCanvas.width, offscreenCanvas.height,
                                        0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // Draw the cursor
        this.drawCircle(mouseX, mouseY, CURSOR_COLOR, cursorRadius);
    }

    function pointerLockActive() {
        return document.pointerLockElement===canvasContainer || document.mozPointerLockElement === canvasContainer;
    }

    // Perform initial canvas setup
    offscreenCtx.clearCanvas();
    ctx.update();

    // Setup pointerlock and fullscreen API functions for cross-browser support
    function addErrorMessage(msg) {
        document.getElementById('msgs').innerHTML += ('<br><font color="red">' + msg + '</font>');
    }

    canvasContainer.requestPointerLock = canvasContainer.requestPointerLock || canvasContainer.mozRequestPointerLock;
    canvasContainer.requestFullscreen = canvasContainer.webkitRequestFullscreen || canvasContainer.mozRequestFullScreen || canvasContainer.msRequestFullscreen
    if (!canvasContainer.requestPointerLock) addErrorMessage('Error: Pointer lock not available');
    if (!canvasContainer.requestFullscreen) addErrorMessage('Error: Full screen mode not available');

    canvasContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

        if (pointerLockActive()) {
            // If in pointer lock, then cursor positions need to be updated manually;
            // Normal cursor positions (e.g. e.clientX and e.clientY) don't get updated in pointer lock
            mouseX += e.movementX, mouseY += e.movementY;

            // Prevent the mouse from moving off-screen
            mouseX = Math.min(Math.max(0, mouseX), canvas.width);
            mouseY = Math.min(Math.max(0, mouseY), canvas.height);
        } else {
            // If pointer lock is inactive, then mouse position is just position relative to canvas offset
            mouseX = (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft)
            mouseY = (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)
        }
        ctx.update();   // Update the onscreen canvas
    }, false);

    // Handle entering and exiting pointer lock; pointer lock status is yoked to full screen status; both are entered and exited at the same time
    document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', function(e) {

        if (!pointerLockActive()) {
            console.log('Pointer lock deactivated');
            canvas.width /= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;
            canvas.height /= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR
            cursorRadius /= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;
            
        } else {
            console.log('Pointer lock activated')
            canvas.width *= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;
            canvas.height *= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;
            cursorRadius *= CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;

            // Set the initial mouse position to be the middle of the canvas
            mouseX = screen.width/2, mouseY = screen.height/2;
        }

        // Update the onscreen canvas
        ctx.update();
    });

    document.getElementById('fullscreen_button').onclick = function(e) {
        // When button is clicked, enter both full screen and pointer lock
        canvasContainer.requestFullscreen();
        var timeout = 2000;
        var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                canvasContainer.requestPointerLock();
            } else if (timeout <= 0) {
                addErrorMessage('Unable to establish pointer lock.');
                clearTimeout(interval);
            } else {
                timeout -= 50;
            }
        }, 50);
        
    }

    canvasContainer.onclick = function(e) {

        console.log('canvasContainer clicked');

        if (pointerLockActive())
            // If pointer lock is active, then use the mouseX and mouseY positions that are manually updated by the mousemove event handler
            var cursorX = mouseX, cursorY = mouseY;
        else
            // Otherwise use the mouse positions passed in the event object
            // If not in full screen mode, the cursor position has to be scaled up, because the mouse position is relative to the onscreen canvas, but we're drawing on the offscreen canvas, which is larger by a factor of fullscreenScale
            var cursorX = (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft)*CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR, cursorY = (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)*CANVAS_SCALING_FACTOR;

        // If the left mouse button is clicked (e.which===1), draw a circle of one color
        // If any other mouse button is clicked, draw a circle of another color
        var color = e.which === 1 ? LEFT_CLICK_COLOR : OTHER_CLICK_COLOR;
        offscreenCtx.drawCircle(cursorX, cursorY, color, circleRadius);
        ctx.update();
    };

    // Detect canvas right-click events. Prevent default behavior (e.g. context menu display) and pass on to the onclick handler to do the rest of the work
    canvasContainer.oncontextmenu = function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        this.onclick(e);
    }

    canvas.onclick = function() {
        console.log('canvas clicked');
    }

    document.onclick = function() {
        console.log('document clicked');
    }

  </script>    

</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry but, when I click on the canvas, it doesn't go to full screen

Comment: Hi, Rishi, do you get an error in the console? What browser are you using? Is it possible you're using a browser that does not support pointer lock or full screen? This works for me in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on Mac, but it does not work in Safari 9, which does not support pointer lock.

Comment: "Blocked pointer lock on an element because the element's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-pointer-lock' permission is not set.
canvas.onclick @ js:52" I am using opera on mac. Opera does support pointer lock

Comment: Hi, Rishi, did you copy the code into a local file and load it, or were you running it by clicking "Run code snippet"? The latter will not work, and will trigger an error like the one you describe. Also, I modified the post with an updated demo and some additional information.

Comment: Thanks, I put it on a local file, and ran it, then it worked. I was able to go to full screen, and everything worked.

Comment: Can I use DOM events with a 3d canvas such as three js?

Comment: I have not tried it specifically, but I don't believe it should be any different from 2d canvas. You can find examples of interactive 3D canvases (e.g. https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_voxelpainter). The question is just whether or not the DOM events will still work in pointer lock, and I assume that this would be the same as for 2d canvases. It would be relatively straightforward to modify some of the three js examples to confirm this is true.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me to handle rightClick after pointer was locked.

```
const onMouseDown = (evt) => {
  switch (evt.which) {
    case 1: return handleLeftClick();
    case 3: return handleRightClick();
  }
};

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, true);
```